# "Your Hang-Ups": Wie übersetzen?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Von Herbie Hancock gibt es ein schönes Stück namens *Hang Up Your Hang-Ups* ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgBrPQCSdW4)). Das Wortspiel wird man nicht übersetzen können, aber kennt jemand einen guten deutschen Ausdruck für *hang-ups*?

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hang-up) sagt: *a source of mental or emotional difficulty*, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hang-up): *an emotional difficulty or a psychological inhibition; a complex* und gibt als Beleg:

> We’re said to have so many hang-ups that we don’t even talk about sex until we’re in the pub, and to need to be blind drunk before anything approaching physical contact occurs.

*Komplexe* wäre ein Kandidat, ist aber einerseits medizinisch und andererseits abwertend, während ich *hang-ups* gerade deshalb als schön empfinde, weil es die *psychischen Probleme* eher harmlos nimmt. Bei [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-german/hang-ups) findet man einen Beleg, wo es mit *Schwächen* übersetzt wird, was aber zu weit ist.

Gibt es umgangssprachliche Ausdrücke, die als Übersetzung dienen könnten?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zwei Möglichkeiten, die mir einfallen, sind »Hemmungen« und »Blockaden«. Beide passen zum genannten Beispiel, wie man auch sagt, dass jemand gehemmt oder blockiert ist. Dann könnte man den Titel wiedergeben als »Hemme deine Hemmungen« bzw. »Blockiere deine Blockaden«.

Comment: Ich hätte nicht gedacht, daß man überhaupt eine Übersetzung für den Titel finden kann, aber das sind zwei gute Vorschläge!

Comment: Hübsch, aber die Verben *hemmen* und *blockieren* sind sehr ungewöhnlich in der Alltagssprache. Mit ihnen klingt der Satz deutlich weniger flüssig und alltagsplausibel als im Englischen. Außerdem haben beide eine negative Konnotation (unerwünscht), beim Überwinden der Hemmungen geht es aber um etwas positiv Erwünschtes. Wie wäre es mit etwas in der Richtung: *Halt' dich mit deiner Zurückhaltung ein bisschen mehr zurück!*? Na. Oder kürzer: ***Halt' deine Zurückhaltung zurück!***

Comment: Oder vielleicht - unter Verzicht auf die Repetition, aber mit Gewinn von Kürze: ***Brems' deine Zurückhaltung!***